# Create WiFi hotspot without internet from laptop

Tags: networking, windows-10, home-networking, hotspot

I’ve been digging into google but I can’t find a proper link to guide me. I want to create a wireless hotspot from my hp laptop to connect three devices to it. I have no access to internet. I need the modem to be like a router so any other devices can see it when they scan for WiFi hotspots. It would be like a house group but without internet.  Anyone can help me? Thanks in advance

Comment: What are you asking for? I see that you want to host a wireless network, but you are not being clear. You say that you want to host a hotspot from your laptop, but then want wireless routing from a modem. A hotspot is a piece of software that broadcasts your internet connection through your wireless card. A hotspot is also referred to as a wireless access point (with a network bridge). A modem is a piece of hardware that receives an internet connection from a coaxial cable and forwards it to either router or some other device connected over a rj45 cable.

Comment: There is an app called Zapya for mobile devices which makes a wireless access point without internet connection. This app somehow works without the bluetooth mode on and without internet and people can share documents and else. They can even create a little network through this app to even play games. So I thought I could do the same with my notebook to create a network as Zapya does

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want seems to be a *peer-to-peer*, or *Hosted Network*. It has been [built into Windows since XP](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/250927/how-to-configure-a-peer-network), but access changed in Windows 8 and 10. Using [Windows 10 built-in capability](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-networking/how-do-i-set-up-an-ad-hoc-wifi-network-in-windows/0caa92d8-e02f-4e7f-aa5c-0abf10ed2039):

- Enable WiFi and turn off *Airplane mode* from the control panel.
- Press <kbd>Windows</kbd> and type `cmd`. Then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> and click `Yes` to confirm UAC for the Administrator CMD prompt.
- Type (or copy/paste) to enter `netsh wlan show drivers`,  listing network drivers. You should see `Hosted network supported  : Yes`... if not, drivers need to be installed or updated.
- [Enter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23168152/use-netsh-wlan-set-hostednetwork-to-create-a-wifi-hotspot-and-the-authenti) `netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=mynetname key=mypwd`, replacing *mynetname* with your chosen *ad hoc* network name, and *mypwd* with your chosen password (8 to 63 characters long).
- Enter `netsh wlan start hostednetwork`to start communication.

There is also a [GUI to set up *ad hoc* networks](https://www.dummies.com/computers/computer-networking/wireless/how-to-set-up-a-wireless-ad-hoc-network), which I find takes a bit longer.

Windows 10  *hosted networks* employ [WPA2 security](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/nativewifi/about-the-wireless-hosted-network) (thanks to @grawity for correction).

Comment: Win8/10 `hostednetwork` is not ad-hoc; it's a regular managed ("infrastructure") network and uses standard WPA2. Same goes for "hotspot" features in most other operating systems. (Though even ad-hoc mode nowadays supports WPA2...)

Comment: Thanks for the replies. Sadly as of Windows 8.1 they removed the option to create Ad Hoc connection. Here’s the link https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/es-ES/8e70ab94-bee3-421a-a1cb-aadf19e33ab9/como-crear-una-red-ad-hoc-en-windows-10?forum=win10itprogeneralES

Comment: @madcoderz, You might try third-party software such as WiFi Ad-hoc Manager, https://download.cnet.com/WiFi-Ad-hoc-Manager/3000-18508_4-76081287.html , or Simple Ad-Hoc Creator, https://sourceforge.net/projects/simpleadhoccreator/ .